# NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.badlogic.gdx.Files.external(String)"

Tags: nullpointerexception, tiled

I'm trying to run a slick 2d example but I get:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.badlogic.gdx.Files.external(String)" because "com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx.files" is null

```
public  class Game extends BasicGame {

private Animation hero, movementUp, movementDown, movementLeft, movementRight, stillUp, stillDown, stillLeft, stillRight;
private Image background;
private char lastDirection;
private float x, y, x2 = 30f, y2 = 25f;
private static final int WIDTH = 640;
private static final int HEIGHT = 480;
private static final float SPEED = 0.1f;
private static final int ANIMATIONSPEED = 500;

TiledMap tiled;
private int maxWidth = 0;
private int maxHeight = 0;
public TmxMapLoader loader ;
public String mapPath="images/map.tmx";
private boolean[][] blocked;
private float mapScale = 1f;

private static final int SIZE = 34;
OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
public Game() {     



    super("Slick2D Animations");


    FileHandle map = Gdx.files.external(mapPath );
    map.writeString(mapPath,false);
    //loader=new TmxMapLoader(new ExternalFileHandleResolver()).load(mapPath);
    tiled.getTileSets();
    tiled=loader.load(mapPath);


}
```

The error line is

```
tiled=loader.load(mapPath)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to make sure you're not using the gdx library before the `create()` method in the ApplicationLauncher class. Move the code into the `create()` method and the problem will be resolved.